# How to pass variables in to a JS file

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax

I know there's an easy answer to this, but this comes in the form of 2 problems.

**Problem 1:**

In an asp.net page there is a javascript block like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSomethingRandom() {
        var myVarToUse = <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="HackyLiteral" />
    }
</script>
```

Ok, so it's a simplified version of the problem, but it should be clear.  I now want to move this function in to a JS file...but I can't get the asp:Literal into the JS.

```
var myVarToUse = <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="HackyLiteral" />
<script src="myJSFile.js" />
```

...Makes me a little sick, is there a better way?

**Problem 2:**

Similar problem, but this time the second version looks like this:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/tree/AttributeTree.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

But this time I can't realistically put the

```
var myVarToUse = <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="HackyLiteral" />
```

above it because with the ScriptManagerProxy there's no real way of knowing exactly where the script file is going to appear.

So, them's the problems!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the `Page`'s [`RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx) method to register initialization functions with the ClientScriptManager. Our Javascript files only contain functions and are loaded via `ScriptManager` (like in your snippet). We wrote an extension method for the Page (called `JSStartupScript`) that helps with registering the startup scripts and at the end of the day our code looks like the following:

```
<%
   Page.JSStartupScript(string.Format("initFeatureX({0}, {1}, {2});",
      AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(ViewData.Property1),
      AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(ViewData.Property2),
      AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(ViewData.Property3)));
%>
```

This also works great in combination with the `ScriptManager`s `CompositeScript` collection and `LoadScriptsBeforeUI = false` setting.

Answer (score 1):

Basically: you can't do that.

What you can do is set the value on the site which is generated by ASP (like you have now) and then refer to that variable from external js scripts, but that's ugly.

The other solution is that you can store this variable in a cookie (which will be set by ASP) and then read that cookie in external JS. You can also pass this value to a URL of a site you are displaying and parse the url in JS to get the value but I think cookies will be better for that since you will still have a clean URL and reading cookie is easier then parsing url params.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an aspx file as a js file.

`\<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/dynamic.aspx") %>"></script>`

The you can do whatever you want in the aspx.

Comment: (remove the slash - stackoverflow wanted to strip out the script tag otherwise)

Comment: You will have caching problems with that solution I'm afraid. If you don't leave dynamic parameter in the link your browser will probably cache it and won't download updated version that might have changed because the id has changed. And if you add dynamic parameter the browser will download this file on every page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to load javascript file dynamically.
I mean something like this

```
<script>
var myVarToUse = <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="HackyLiteral" />
ComponentLoad("/tree/AttributeTree.js"); //here Javascript file will be loaded
</script>
```

But even this is not the best solution. Because there will be a lot of global variables than.
So better to do this:

```
<script>
ComponentLoad("/tree/AttributeTree.js","doSomethingRandom",{myVarToUse:"<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="HackyLiteral" />"}); //here Javascript file will be loaded
</script>
```