# Embed server side code in the separate JavaScript files

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

Imagine you have an application that consists C# .NET code for the server side, and JavaScript files on the client side. As you know you can embed server side code by using `<% %>` tags, or other tags like @ id you are using MVC razor view engine.

Now imagine you have separate JavaScript files that are loaded by the script tag in the head tag: how can I embed server side code into the code in the JavaScript files? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Send the header "Content-type: text/javascript" and load it as

`<script type="text/javascript" src="whatever.aspx?whatever=someparm"></script>`

For example

Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";

or

Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "text/javascript");

Perhaps you can do this: [How to pass variables in to a JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259208/how-to-pass-variables-in-to-a-js-file)